# What Yammer clients available on the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adobe-flash

People in my new job seems to like Yammer. I'm aware that Yammer has a desktop client for the Mac, but I find the interface rather unappealing (version 300222 of the Adobe Air client is not responsive and really slow when switching between my primary network and external networks). I wonder if there are 3rd party clients available?

Comment: Would you be willing to expound on how a specific version of the yammer client doesn't work for you. We have a nice summary of the [problems with vaguely written requests](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) and with some edits, this could be much more educational and likely an expert can share their experience with you to find better software recommendations.

Comment: Thanks! Now that's something we can try to get you a better answer to attack the slowness of a non-native app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two out there that I like, each for different reasons:

1. [Gabble](http://gabbleapp.com) is a free application that allows for threaded conversations, private and public groups, attachments, and tags.
2. [Scuttlebutt](http://scuttlebuttapp.com/) is an application in beta.  The major thing that it improves over Gabble is support for multiple Yammer accounts (although there is a workaround for that in Gabble: you can launch multiple Gabble instances).

Both of these software are native OS X apps and should be much faster to use than an Adobe Air client as well as have the potential to support things like spelling services, voice dictation and other nice integrations that a native app can provide more easily than using a cross-platform toolbox.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of Scuttlebutt. Scuttlebutt is a native app – although not really optimized yet since it's still in beta. Would you mind explaining a bit further why do you feel that Scuttlebutt is slow?

Comment: Sorry, that's an error in my original message.  I do generally find Scuttlebutt slow, but it's the native Yammer app that's Air and not yours.  Sending and receiving messages doesn't feel instantaneous, which is something I expect out of an instant messenger.  I have to admit that I've stopped using Yammer (I no longer work for an employer that uses it) so haven't tried your app in the past few months.

Comment: Thanks for that. There were some enhancements done in early March about sending/receiving messages and it should feel faster – let me know if you use Yammer again and able to try out the more recent releases.

Comment: Just tried the Gabble app, but the authorization crashes out. Given there is a 2010 date on the app, it may no longer work with the Mac, or maybe just Mavericks?

Answer (score 0):

There is Gabble, you can download from here:

http://gabbleapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Gabble is dead, as Yammer requires a new authorisation method that isn't included in the dated Gabble app.  I'm waiting for Scuttlebutt to send me the download link to see if that has the same problem.

MS has also pulled the AIR app, so don't produce a Mac-compatible app anymore.